# Проблема с кодировкой при кириллице в названии файла

Tags: java

Есть файл с кириллицей "C:/крис280917.rar" который мне нужно разархивировать с помощью junrar

```
     String filename = "C:/крис280917.rar";
    File f = new File(filename);
    Archive a = null;
    try {
        a = new Archive(new FileVolumeManager(f));
    } catch (RarException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (a != null) {
        a.getMainHeader().print();
        FileHeader fh = a.nextFileHeader();
        String value = null;
        try {
            value = new String(fh.getFileNameString().trim().getBytes("UTF-8"), "Windows-1251");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (fh != null) {
            try {
                File out = new File("C:/unrar/" + value);
                System.out.println(out.getAbsolutePath());
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);
                a.extractFile(fh, os);
                os.close();
            } catch (RarException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fh = a.nextFileHeader();
        }
    }
```

Я перепробовал множество кодировок но так и не смог подобрать правильную с

```
   ("UTF-8"), "Windows-1251")
```

получаю ответ

```
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\unrar\пїЅпїЅпїЅ280917\0266\201709291022.tar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
```

Comment: cp866 или cp1251

Comment: попробуйте вместо `getFileNameString()` вызвать `getFileNameW()`. А исключение вы получаете, потому что промежуточных папок нет, можно их создать чем-то вроде `out.getParentFile().mkdirs();`

Comment: getFileNameString() и out.getParentFile().mkdirs(); помогло

Answer (score 1):

Здесь на самом то деле речь идет о 3-х кодировках:

1. Кодировка имени файла в файловой системе (запустите `CMD.EXE` и наберите `chcp`, чтобы увидеть кодировку символов используемых в названии - с большой вероятностью это `CP-866`
2. Кодировка имени файла в вашей программе (посмотрите настройки IDE, в котором набран ваш текст `крис280917.rar` - возможно `Windows-1251` или `UTF-8`)
3. Кодировка выдачи об ошибке - с большой вероятностью это `UTF-8`

Вам надо имя файла транслировать с кодировки №2 в кодировку №1.

Comment: 866,IDEA: Global encoding windows-1251,project encoding UTF-8, при ("866"), "UTF-8") и ("866"), "Windows-1251") получаю FileNotFoundException: C:\unrar\???280917\0266\201709291022.tar

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать меня в качестве отладчика - то вы жестоко ошибаетесь :)